# jQuery function to change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contents').hide();
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).siblings('.contents').slideToggle(200, function () {
            $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'close' : 'open');
        });
    });
});
```

and would like to add a further function to the click function. I'm new to jQuery and tried to learn but still does not understand to read it. I thought I can create and append an if-clause but still struggle with that.
So I have something like that:

```
$this.css($('.year').is(':visible') ? 'color', 'red' : 'color', 'green');
if the click function takes place and the .contents is visible change the css setting of .year to red and if not use color green
```

It would be great if someone can help me out.

Thanks alot.

Comment: `$this.css('color', $('.year').is(':visible') ? 'red' : 'green');` (Move the `'color',`part before the ?:)

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. this does not work. maybe i forgot to say somehting. i will update my question.

Comment: Note that `.is(':visible')` will return true if any element with the `.year` class is visible, if you have more than one element with that class it can be an issue.

Comment: Note that elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible. Visible elements need to have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/m6WrV/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle(200, function () {
            $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'click to close' : 'click to open');
            $(this).closest('.aai').find('.head').css('color', $(this).is(':visible') ? 'red' : 'green');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, but honestly, Rob W gives you the answer 47 min ago :)

Comment: I think, `$(this).parent()` can be used instead of `$(this).closest('.aai')`.

Comment: @JustinJohn Could be here of course but at least closest let you modify html without having to re-encode function, e.g, if you wish to wrap .slide element in other wrapper. .parents('.aai').first() is an other option.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you looking for something like

```
$this.css( 'color', $('.year').is(':visible') ? 'red' : 'green') );
```

You maybe also have to check if how `is(':visible')` works on the set of returned elements from `$('.year')`. Could be that is works different when some are visible and others aren't.

edit: as @adeneo points out, `is(':visible')` returns true if *any* element in the set is visible.

Comment: hello and thanks for abswering. this does not work. i already updated my question. have a look at the if-clause comment. thanks.

Comment: How do you use the proposed code? What happens, and what does not happen? Maybe you can make as JS Fiddle to show it better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m6WrV/ here you can see it. now i would like to change the color if the headline to red when the click function takes place. So if the content is visible change color of headline.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might work for you but the code is not as concise
 as your snippet:

```
if ($(".year").is(":visible")) {
   $this.css({ "color" : "red" });
} else {
   $this.css({ "color" : "green" });
}
```

Comment: Wrap `:visible` with quotes i.e `is(":visible")`.

Comment: Thanks I totally missed that

Comment: jsfiddle.net/m6WrV here you can see it. i would like to change the color of the headline to red when the click function takes place. So if the content is visible change color of headline.